# access HTTPSession with javaagent

Tags: java, servlets, agent, httpsession, javassist

Is there a way to access session attributes while instrumenting called methods with a javaagent written in javassist?

I'm trying with spring web doing the following code in the agent:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session =  attr.getRequest().getSession();
```

but I get the following error:

> Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
>   found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
>   web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
>   receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
>   and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
>   of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request

Comment: What error did you get? Post stacktrace.

Comment: Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.